# Visual Code não executa projeto

Tags: visual-studio-code

Pessoal estou com dificuldade para executar um projeto no visual code!

Segue o passo de instalação do github : github.com/aspnet/home#upgrading-dnvm-or-running-without-visual-studio

CMD

```
@powershell -NoProfile -ExecutionPolicy unrestricted -Command "&{$Branch='dev';iex ((new-object net.webclient).DownloadString(raw.githubusercontent.com/aspnet/Home/dev/dnvminstall.ps1'))}"
```

verifiquei o path depois digitei o comando dnvm upgrade
rodou certo esta funcionando mas não consigo executar nenhum projeto na linha de comando

[image: SS]

depois criei na pasta c:\temp\VS\DNX\  e coloque dois arquivos um teste.cs e o outro é o project.json

quando executo não funciona!
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Você resolveu joão?